# Issues extending an XSD schema with any elements

Tags: xml, xsd, xml-validation

I have an application that tries to validate the following XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<cnt:agenda xmlns:cnt="urn:ppp:contacts"
    xmlns:cnt2="urn:ppp:contactsv2"
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="urn:ppp:contactsv2 contactsv2.xsd urn:ppp:contacts contacts.xsd ">
    <cnt:entry>
        <cnt:number>12345678</cnt:number>
    </cnt:entry>
    <cnt:entry>
        <cnt:number>12345678</cnt:number>
        <cnt2:personal-info>
           <cnt2:genre>male</cnt2:genre>
           <cnt2:age>30</cnt2:age>
        </cnt2:personal-info>
    </cnt:entry>
</cnt:agenda>
```

In order to fulfill that, I have these two XSD schemas:

**contacts.xsd**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema
   targetNamespace="urn:ppp:contacts"
   xmlns="urn:ppp:contacts"
   xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
   elementFormDefault="qualified" attributeFormDefault="unqualified">

  <xs:element name="agenda">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence maxOccurs="unbounded">
        <xs:element name="entry" type="entry-type"/>
        <xs:any namespace="##other" processContents="lax" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>

  <xs:complexType name="entry-type">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="display-name" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
      <xs:element name="number" type="xs:string"/>
      <xs:any namespace="##other" processContents="lax" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
    </xs:sequence>
    <xs:anyAttribute namespace="##other" processContents="lax"/>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
```

and **contactsv2.xsd**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema targetNamespace="urn:ppp:contactsv2"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:cnt2="urn:ppp:contactsv2"
    xmlns:cnt="urn:ppp:contacts"
    elementFormDefault="qualified" attributeFormDefault="unqualified">

    <xs:import namespace="urn:ppp:contacts" schemaLocation="contacts.xsd"/>

    <!-- Child of entry element --> 
    <xs:element name="personal-info"
    type="cnt2:personal-infoType" />

    <xs:complexType name="personal-infoType">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="genre"
                type="xs:string" />
            <xs:element name="age" type="xs:unsignedByte" minOccurs="0"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
```

As you can see, the second schema extends the first one for adding some new child to *entry* element. At this point, I have found some issues:

1. If an extended element is typed incorrectly (for example, *gere* instead of *genre*) the validator does not give any error. I know that this is because of having lax as the value of processContents  attribute of all the *any* elements, but I'm not supposed to change *contacts.xsd* schema. So, can I bypass this behavior somehow?
2. Can I control somehow where are the extended elements added? Because if I add the *personal-info* element as a child of *agenda* the validator says that the document is valid, and I want to let only appear that element as a child of *entry*.

Note: I cannot use XSD 1.1 version

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure whether "no" counts as an answer, but I don't think there is an easy solution to either problem. You could try modifying the given schema without really modifying it by using xs:redefine, but personally I hate that feature, and find it far preferable to modify the supplied schema as a source document (perhaps controlling the process by making the modifications repeatable, via an XSLT stylesheet).